# Programmatically set Inno Setup Uninstall window caption

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to change the title of the window at the uninstall?

We need to do this using code, similarly to this code for install window caption:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.Caption := 'Setup Application';
end;
```

Comment: please clarify your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use `UninstallProgressForm` global variable from [`InitializeUninstallProgressForm` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstallProgressForm) to access uninstall form.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  UninstallProgressForm.Caption := 'Uninstalling';
end;
```